# How to prove this Logarithmic identity?

Tags: logarithms

I am just learning logs, and can't get this one out ? How to prove that

$$ \log_a (b) \cdot \log_b (c) = \log_a (c) $$ in the format : `log [base]([argument])`   
thank you .

Comment: Try to translate into a statement about exponentials, by introducing new variables: $\log_a b= x$, so $a^x=b$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Express all in base $\;a\;$ (change of base property):

$$\log_ab\cdot\log_bc=\log_ab\frac{\log_ac}{\log_ab}=\ldots$$

Comment: I feel embarrased ... I really don't believe that i did not see this . Thank you .ps don't have enough credit to vote up.